# What is typical "Cost Per Million Requests" for a typical Google AppEngine content app? (e.g. CMS, forum, etc.)

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud-hosting

We have an app that on average has 30 QPS (*queries per second*) and our costs around $1 per hour what gives a rough number for **our GAE costs: $1 per million requests**.

About half of this requests is to serve content (*to real clients and search engines's bots*) and another half is deferred tasks that update entities, reset cache, pre-generate some HTML, etc. We do not use backends anymore (we did but found it too difficult to sync during deployments and moved everything to task queues and are not looking back).

Just wonder how it is comparing to others? Normal? Too much? Very good?

I'm asking before we've got a new member in our team who is agitating that our costs are too high and we need to migrate to our own stand-alone server(s).

Am newbie at StackOverflow and not sure if I should/can disclose the name of the website in question (*I would be happy to provide if it is allowed*).

Comment: 30 QPS (requests per second?) is ~100k requests/hour, at $1 per hour this would be about $10 per 1M requests. We are seeing _about_ the same.

Comment: How much will the new servers cost to maintain,backup,replace 24/7 I wonder.....

Comment: The biggest saving comes from the fact that you do not need system admins.